# How to use SELECT(sql) with multiple checkboxes?

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I have 2 multiple checkboxes and have problems to display it correct if more than one checkbox is ticked. Only the last checkbox get used for the filter in the Select query.

I was searching a lot in the web, but I don't find someone who has also a problem with this.

**Question:**
How to use SELECT(sql) with multiple checkboxes?

HTML Code:

```
<aside><h3>Filter:</h3>
    <details open="open">
    <summary><label>Categorie</label></summary>
        <div>
            <label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="filter_categorie[]" value="dog">
            Dogs
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="filter_categorie[]" value="fish">
            Fishes
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="filter_categorie[]" value="other">
            Other
            </label>
        </div>
    </details>
    <details>
    <summary><label>Land</label></summary>
        <div>
            <label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="filter_country[]" value="germany">
            Germany
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>
            <input  type="checkbox" name="filter_country[]" value="austria">
            Austria
            </label>
        </div>
    </details>

    <br><input type='submit' name ='update' value='Update'>
```

PHP Code:

```
include("server.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("No connection to Server");
if(isset($_POST['update']) ){
    foreach ($_POST['filter_categorie[]'] as $item){
        $query = "
        SELECT * 
          FROM artikel 
         WHERE Categorie=\"{$_POST['filter_categorie']}\"
";}
$resultat = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die ("No results.");
```

Comment: You didn't use `as $item`. You're passing the POST array instead.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers_

Comment: @mplungjan, TBH I think they want it something like `Categorie in ( )`.

Comment: @NigelRen I am sure a better suggestion was available. OPs version will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (not tested, its just an idea):

```
include("server.inc");
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database) or die ("No connection to Server");
if(isset($_POST['update']) ){

  $query = 'SELECT * FROM artikel WHERE Categorie IN ('.implode(',', $_POST['filter_categorie']).')';

  $resultat = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die ("No results.");
}
```

So basically use `$_POST['filter_categorie']` not `$_POST['filter_categorie[]']` and use implode to give all categories as a string in you query.

No need to use foreach, you don't want to run as many queries as many selections of categories in the front end.

Comment: Me too :) at least give the reason

Comment: @ivanivan Thank you!

Comment: Did not downvote, but the statement should be `Categorie IN (x,y,z)` instead of `Categorie IN "x,y,z"`.

Comment: If anyone uses this solution, you still need to escape it the user input.